# Scaffold Identity fails in .Net5 Blazor Server

Tags: identity, blazor-server-side, .net-5, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I have an existing .Net 5 Blazor Server application. No authentication or authorization at this point. I am attempting to add Microsoft Identity via scaffolding but continue to get the the following error when I attempt to scaffold Identity into the project which I can not resolve "There was an error in the selected code generator 'Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes [MySolujtionName] Server."

Thing's I have tried:

- Batch-Build - Clean Solution
- Batch Build - Rebuild Solution
- Tools --> Options --> Nuget Package Manager --> Clear All Nuget Caches then repeat above steps

So far no luck and I continue to get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried with a new Blazor Server project and it works with:

1. Specify at least one override (I've selected *Login*, *Logout* and *Registration*)
2. Specify the full path of the _Layout.cshtml (I've used */Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/_Layout.cshtml*)
3. Add a Context
4. Add a User model

then the scaffolding works as expected.

I obtain the following structure:

[image]

The **User** model class generated by the scaffolder will be:

```
namespace Test2.Areas.Identity.Data
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the Test2User class
    public class Test2User : IdentityUser
    {
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

I've found a bug in the Visual Studio Generator.
The only possibility to scaffold the Identity pages from an existing project is to execute the scaffolding process via command line.

Here is an example of the command line:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc TestWasmAuthIndividual.Server.Data.ApplicationDbContext --files "Account.Register;Account.Login;Account.Logout;Account.Manage.PersonalData" --force
```

you need to execute this command line from the **Server** project.

Comment: Hi Nicola - I had already done 1, 2 and 3. What are you using for a User Model? I selected override all.

Comment: I've added the generated user class to the answer.
I haven't written any user class, the scaffolder creates it for me.

Comment: I think the problem should be some old or _in preview_ packages you already had in the existing project. Try to create a new Blazor Server project and use a source text comparer.

Comment: No old or preview packages

Comment: Are you sure you're `TargetFramework` in csproj is correct?

Comment: everyuthing targets .Net5

Comment: Have you tried with command line? See my update.

Comment: I will give UPDATE cmd line a try

Comment: UPDATE above was the answer - worked very well - thank you Nicolas

Answer (score 3):

I copied and pasted this from Nicolas Biada above to point out that this was the part that was the actual resolution.

UPDATE

I've found a bug in the Visual Studio Generator.
The only possibility to scaffold the Identity pages from an existing project is to execute the scaffolding process via command line.

Here is an example of the command line:

dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc TestWasmAuthIndividual.Server.Data.ApplicationDbContext --files "Account.Register;Account.Login;Account.Logout;Account.Manage.PersonalData" --force

you need to execute this command line from the Server project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Blazor Server. I started my project with Identity templated and I'm getting errors when I try the command line solution above.

The errors I got after trying to scaffold pages are ones that make me think the scaffolder doesn't really understand the conventions around Blazor. The scaffolder fails to build (even though a normal build completes) because of things like Component Lifecycle methods, Singleton references in _ViewImports.cshtml, and references to the components themselves...
[Screengrab 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORPpE.png)
[Screengrab 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhqrJ.png)

I'm using Net 5.0, I'm not sure if this is already solved in Net 6.0.

I ended up deleting my Components folder and all references to them. Scaffolded all the pages (so I don't have to do this again), then restored the folder using version control.